# Pasar variables de un javascript a un html

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas,tengo el siguiente script jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").on("click", function() {
        var img = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        var p = $(this).children('p').text(); 
        });
       });
   </script>
```

Que recoge  los datos de:

```
  <a href="#">
   <img src="img/bebe.jpg" alt="">
   <p>prueba 1</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <img src="img/taller.jpg" alt="">
   <p>prueba 2</p>
  </a>
```

Quiero enviar esas variables de javascript a otra página HTML.

Comment: ¿Has hecho una búsqueda en el sitio primero? Hay [más de 100 publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=variable+de+javascript+a+php) con información sobre cómo pasar variables de JavaScript a PHP y viceversa. Esta pregunta podría ser un duplicado de muchas de esas. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 3):

Pues haces un GET o un POST pasando los datos que quieras al servidor (PHP).

EJEMPLO con POST (mejor para los datos que quieres pasar)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function() {
    var img = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    var p = $(this).children('p').text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/tu/url',
        data: {'img':img,'p':p},
        success: function(data) {
          //success actions
        },
        dataType: 'json'
      });
    });
   });
```

Si los campos a pasar los tienes dentro de un formulario, el data puede pasar a ser directamente

```
data : $('#<mi_form_id>').serialize()
```

Comment: No sabes si esta usando ajax o no...

Comment: @LombardaArda ¿Qué relevancia tiene si ya está usando o no? Puede usarlo leyendo esta respuesta... ¿O te referías a jQuery en vez de AJAX?

Comment: @Mariano en las etiquetas aparece PHP y javascript por eso lo decia, a lo mejor busca una respuesta puramente en PHP y javasript.

Comment: rectifico,mi problema es enviar esas variables javascript a una pagina html

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la API de LocalStorage para no tener que pasar por PHP.

Por ejemplo :

```
<script>

   //A esta funcion de abajo la llamas cuando veas necesario, despues de un click podría ser tu caso, recibe dos parametros, el src que capturaste y el texto del parrafo. 
   $(document).ready(function(){

   function poblarLocalStorage(vsrc,vparrafo){

      localStorage.setItem("srcLlamada",vsrc); //src es el nombre por el cual accederemos
      localStorage.setItem("parrafoLlamada",vparrafo); //ParrafoLlamada lo mismo.
   }



    $("a").on("click", function() {
    var img = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    var p = $(this).children('p').text(); 

    //***Aqui llamo a la funcion que realicé **//

    poblarLocalStorage(img,p);  //Img y p son las variables que capturaste
    });
   });

 </script>


  //Ahora para llamar a esas variables en otra ventana. 
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   //Suponiendo que tenes unos Id en unos nuevos <p> y <img>

   function recuperarDatosLocalStorage (){

      var img = document.getElementById("imagen");
      var parrafo = document.getElementById("parrafo");

      img = localstorage.getItem("srcLlamada");
      parrafo = localstorage.getItem("parrafoLlamada")
   }

   //Llamo a la funcion RecuperarDatos.

    recuperarDatosLocalStorage();
  });
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A ver qué empiezo a ver lío de conceptos.
Para empezar

```
$(document).ready
```

implica qué está usando jQuery.

Luego, "de javascript a HTML" implica qué no quieres procesado en el lado de servidor? es decir el elemento  simplemente modificará algún otro elemento del DOM (HTML ya generado) ante clicks ? Por ponerte un ejemplo tonto : Una caja de texto qué muestra el attribute SRC del img y un elemento <span> qué también :

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    $('#myinputID').val(imgSrc);
    $('#myspanID').html(imgSrc);
});
```

Cada elemento del DOM (HTML) se instanciará cómo corresponda.

Hasta aquí no veo necesidad de librerías adicionales tipo localStorage.

Aunque he especulado porque ya no veo muy claro lo qué buscas. Si especificas un poco más te podemos ayudar mejor :)

Answer (score 0):

Dado el comentario *rectifico,mi problema es enviar esas variables javascript a una pagina html* actualizo mi respuesta.

Para pasar una variable javascript de una pagina html a otra puedes usar `localStorage`.

Así añades una variable al `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("nombre_variable",variable);
```

Y así la obtienes:

```
localStorage.getItem("nombre_variable");
```

Comment: rectifico,mi problema es enviar esas variables javascript a una pagina html

Comment: @Borch he editado mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

**Para comunicarse entre páginas debes utilizar los formularios.**

Pueden ir a través de GET o escoger por el método POST de formulario.

> PaginaInicial.html:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="PaginaDos.html" name="FormEnvioDatos" id="FormEnvioDatos" method="get">

    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/bebe.jpg" alt="">
        <p>prueba 1</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="Prueba1" name="Prueba1" value="Prueba 1" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/taller.jpg" alt="">
        <p>prueba 2</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="Prueba2" name="Prueba2" value="Prueba 2" />
    </a>
    <input type="hidden" id="imgDesdeLaPagina1" name="imgDesdeLaPagina1" value="" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('a').click(function () {
            var imgSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
            $('#imgDesdeLaPagina1').val(imgSrc);
            document.getElementById("FormEnvioDatos").submit();
        });

    });
</script>
```

> PaginaDos.html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="ImagenPintar" src="" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var urlParamImagen = ObtenerValorDelaImagen("imgDesdeLaPagina1");

        $("#ImagenPintar").attr("src", urlParamImagen);
        function ObtenerValorDelaImagen(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {

                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                }
            }
        }
 });
    </script>
```