# Insertar un valor en HTML con JavaScript

Tags: html

Tengo ahora mismo en el `JS`

```
let valor = "hola"

document.getElementById('precio').value = valor
```

Y lo quiero insertar en el `html` que ahora mismo tengo:

```
      <h2 id="error">Precio: </h2>
      <span id="precio"></span>
```

Pero no me funciona y he visto en algunas ocasiones que se debería hacer así, ¿cómo lo puedo cambiar?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133028/pasar-variables-de-un-javascript-a-un-html

Answer (score 0):

```
let valor = "hola"

document.getElementById('precio').textContent = valor
```

**Usá textContent en lugar de innerHTML para evitar ataques XSS.**

> innerHTML retorna el HTML como su nombre indica. Con bastante frecuencia, para leer o escribir texto en un elemento, la gente usa innerHTML. textContent debería usarse en su lugar. Ya que el texto no es procesado es más probable que tenga mejor rendimiento. Además, esto evita un vector de ataques XSS. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

[Más info sobre textContent vs innerHTML (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext)